# Load new module in Kamailio

Tags: sip-server, kamailio, openser

I would like to ask, how can I load new module in Kamailio 4.1.2?
Actually, I have an issue, when I tried to compile my `kamaiio.cfg`
I've got error:

```
root@kamailio:/usr/local/# kamailio -c kamailio.cfg
loading modules under /usr/local/lib64/kamailio/modules/
 0(25392) ERROR: <core> [sr_module.c:587]: load_module(): ERROR: load_module: could not find module <websocket> in </usr/local/lib64/kamailio/modules/>
 0(25392) : <core> [cfg.y:3408]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 323, column 12-25: failed to load module
 0(25392) ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3272]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command ws_handle_handshake
 0(25392) : <core> [cfg.y:3411]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 1083, column 27: unknown command, missing loadmodule?

ERROR: bad config file (2 errors)
```

when I look physically to the `/usr/local/lib64/kamailio/modules/` there is some modules, but `websocket.so` is missing.
So, how can I get and load module in Kamailio?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't installed the module **websocket**. Edit modules.lst file in the source code directory and add websocket to include_modules variable. If you don't have modules.lst, just do:

```
make cfg
```

Alternative is to do:

```
make cfg include_modules="websocket"
```

By default, the build system for kamailio compiles and install only the modules that have the same dependencies as the core of the application. For websocket you need to install libunistring and openssl (libssl) devel packages.

Comment: yes exactly, I fixed it before, I just forgot update this tread.
Thank you

Comment: Do we need to do anything after modifying modules.lst file? When will this new module install on the current server? During restart of Kamailio?

Comment: You have to reinstall kamailio (do 'make install' again) and then restart it.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**  to load new module to **Kamailio** server. (Try if above answer is not working for you)

1. Check the modules is exist in the default module directly **/usr/local/lib64/kamailio/modules**.
   If found, add ***loadmodule "module_name.so*"** in load module section in **kamailio.cfg** file.
2. If the module is not found in default module directory, you can check for the source code of that module in the default module source code directory **/usr/local/src/kamailio-4.4/kamailio/modules**.
3. If source code found, enter to the module directory. Then create modules' shared object file(.so) by following commands.

   ./configure
   make
   make test
   make install
4. Then you will get a shared object file(.so). Copy that file into the default module directory. and load this module from the ***kamailio.cfg*** file as mentioned in step 1.
5. If module source code does not exist in the default source code directory, You need to download the source code from the web. And follow step 3 and 4.